How to draw line in real time by Polyline Osmdroid
I'm use Osmdroid lib and I want draw line in real time while user moves.
It's true in points recieved data from pos but line is not appears on the map.
What's wrong here?
`GeoPoint pos = new GeoPoint(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    Polyline line = new Polyline();
    ArrayList<GeoPoint> points = new ArrayList<>();
    points.add(pos);
    line.setPoints(points);
    line.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    line.setGeodesic(true);
    map.getOverlays().add(line);
    map.invalidate();`

when I try this
GeoPoint pos = new GeoPoint(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()); GeoPoint pos2 = new GeoPoint(50.5, 50.5); Polyline line = new Polyline(); line.addPoint(pos); line.addPoint(pos2); line.setColor(Color.BLACK); line.setGeodesic(true); map.getOverlays().add(line); map.invalidate();
line appears
